# Convert List<String> to Mono<List<String<>> Java WebFlux

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I'm trying to convert a list of string to Mono of List of String in Java using web WebFlux, maybe its easy but I can't find the solution.

This is the List

```
List<String> lstString = new ArrayList<>();
lstString.add("Hello");
lstString.add("How");
lstString.add("are");
lstString.add("you?");


//Expected result
Mono<List<String>> lstMonoList =lstString.stream.map()....
```

I tried to use stream, flatmap and map methods but often I get response as stream() o List

Can anyone help me?,
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

If you want to wrap it in a mono then, use `Mono.just(lstString);`. I would recommend looking at the documentation for [Mono](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html) & [Flux](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html) as well.

Comment: Thanks @duppydodah, it works perfectly